# Store CSS value in var based on a functions parameter and then manipulate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several elements that I want to manipulate on a '.hover' event via the CSS property 'max-width'. However all of them have different values, for example one is 25% and another is 60%, and I would prefer to create one function that takes in a given element, stores it's max-width value and then uses it in an animation later rather than create multiple functions or lines of code for all possible scenarios. Here is an example of what I mean with pseudocode

```
function Hover (element) {
    var maxwidth = $(element).css({'max-width': 'value'}); //something like this perhaps?
    $(element).hover(
        function () {
            $(this).animate({'max-width': maxwidth + 5%}, "slow"); //actually use the var in the css call
        },
        function () {
            $(this).animate({'max-width': maxwidth(original value)}, "slow"); //then restore the original value 
        }
    ); 
}
```

Hopefully what i'm trying to do makes sense here. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is how you can take the value

```
var maxwidth = $(element).css('max-width');
```

Perhaps for collection you will have to use $.each

```
var collection = [];
$(element).each(function(){
   collection.push($(this).css('max-width'))
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats certainly the line i want for the var. But why would width be any better than just using max-width?

Comment: I haven't try animating that way, but since small investigation I think it is possible, so good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that accepts a value parameter to be added onto the existing value of a width of an element. You could change the code to use the value parameter as a percentage, and then just modify the calculation of newWidth for use with a percentage.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#test").mouseenter(function() {
    setNewWidth(this.id,100);
  });
  
});


function setNewWidth(id,newWidth) {
 var oldWidth = $("#" + id).css('width');
 var n = oldWidth.replace(/px/,"");
 n = newWidth+parseInt(n);
 newWidth = n+"px"
 
 $("#"+id).animate({
  width: newWidth
 }, {
  duration: 500,
  complete: function() { 
   $("#"+id).animate({width:oldWidth},500); 
  }
 });
}
```

```css
button {
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

To use a percentage change the following line:

```
n = ((parseInt(n)/100) * newWidth)+ (parseInt(n));
```

You could also pass in duration as a parameter and use it when setting the 'duration' animation attribute, instead of hard coding it like I did with the value of '500'.